# Spring Struts 1 advice is not being invoked

Tags: spring, struts2, struts, struts-1, struts-config

Our project architecture uses Struts 1 and Struts 2 with Spring 3. I am trying to create an Aspect for better exception handling. Struts 1 was until now not Spring managed - So I followed this link [How to integrate an old Struts application with Spring 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835910/how-to-integrate-an-old-struts-application-with-spring-3-x) to allow Spring component-scan to pick up the Struts 1 Action.

Edit: - Versions

Struts 1 - org.apache.struts.struts-core (1.3.10)
Struts 2 - org.apache.struts.struts2-core (2.0.9)
Spring - 3.2.2

But my aspect class does not pick it up. I don't face any problems with my struts 2 actions or service classes. But I am unable to understand what is wrong here.

The Exception Aspect class -

```
package com.mnm.abc.aop;
public @Aspect @Component class ExceptionHandler {
    @Pointcut("execution(public * abc.web.action.AbcAction+.doExecute(..))")
    public void inStruts1Action() {
    }

/* I tried the following too
* @Pointcut("within(abc.web.action.AbcAction+)")
* @Pointcut("execution(public * abc.web.action.AbcAction.execute(..))")
* @Pointcut("execution(public * abc.web.action.*.doExecute(..)) && within(abc.web.action.AbcAction+)")
*/
    @After("inStruts1Action()")
    public void after() {
        System.out.println("After");
    }
}
```

The Struts 1 Action class -

```
package abc.web.action;
public @Component class TransactionAction extends AbcAction {
    public @Override ActionForward doExecute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Hi");
        ActionForward forward = mapping.findForward("success");
        return forward;
    }
}
```

The Parent class -

```
package abc.web.action;
public abstract class AbcAction extends Action {
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
        try {
            return doExecute(mapping, form, request, response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
    }
    public abstract ActionForward doExecute(ActionMapping mapping,
            ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception;
}
```

The Configuration class -

```
package com.mnm.abc.config;
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "abc.web.action", "com.mnm.abc.aop" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)
public class DataSourceConfig implements TransactionManagementConfigurer { ... }
```

When I went through the debug logs I get the following messages

```
Identified candidate component class: file [C:\...\abc\web\action\TransactionAction.class]
...
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'transactionAction'
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Creating instance of bean 'transactionAction'
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Eagerly caching bean 'transactionAction' to allow for resolving potential circular references
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator  - Creating implicit proxy for bean 'transactionAction' with 0 common interceptors and 2 specific interceptors
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Creating CGLIB2 proxy: target source is SingletonTargetSource for target object [abc.web.action.TransactionAction@1d3981c]
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Unable to apply any optimisations to advised method: public org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward abc.web.action.TransactionAction.doExecute(org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping,org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.lang.Exception
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Unable to apply any optimisations to advised method: public org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward abc.web.action.AbcAction.execute(org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping,org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.lang.Exception
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Unable to apply any optimisations to advised method: protected org.apache.struts.util.MessageResources org.apache.struts.action.Action.getResources(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Unable to apply any optimisations to advised method: protected org.apache.struts.util.MessageResources org.apache.struts.action.Action.getResources(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.lang.String)
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Unable to apply any optimisations to advised method: public org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward org.apache.struts.action.Action.execute(org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping,org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm,javax.servlet.ServletRequest,javax.servlet.ServletResponse) throws java.lang.Exception
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Unable to apply any optimisations to advised method: protected java.util.Locale org.apache.struts.action.Action.getLocale(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Unable to apply any optimisations to advised method: protected void org.apache.struts.action.Action.setLocale(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Locale)
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Unable to apply any optimisations to advised method: public org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet org.apache.struts.action.Action.getServlet()
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Unable to apply any optimisations to advised method: public void org.apache.struts.action.Action.setServlet(org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet)
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Unable to apply any optimisations to advised method: protected boolean org.apache.struts.action.Action.isCancelled(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Unable to apply any optimisations to advised method: protected org.apache.struts.action.ActionMessages org.apache.struts.action.Action.getErrors(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Unable to apply any optimisations to advised method: protected void org.apache.struts.action.Action.addMessages(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.apache.struts.action.ActionMessages)
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Unable to apply any optimisations to advised method: protected void org.apache.struts.action.Action.addErrors(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.apache.struts.action.ActionMessages)
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Unable to apply any optimisations to advised method: protected boolean org.apache.struts.action.Action.isTokenValid(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,boolean)
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Unable to apply any optimisations to advised method: protected boolean org.apache.struts.action.Action.isTokenValid(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Unable to apply any optimisations to advised method: protected void org.apache.struts.action.Action.resetToken(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Unable to apply any optimisations to advised method: protected void org.apache.struts.action.Action.saveErrors(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.apache.struts.action.ActionMessages)
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Unable to apply any optimisations to advised method: protected void org.apache.struts.action.Action.saveErrors(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.apache.struts.action.ActionErrors)
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Unable to apply any optimisations to advised method: protected void org.apache.struts.action.Action.saveMessages(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.apache.struts.action.ActionMessages)
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Unable to apply any optimisations to advised method: protected void org.apache.struts.action.Action.saveMessages(javax.servlet.http.HttpSession,org.apache.struts.action.ActionMessages)
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Unable to apply any optimisations to advised method: protected void org.apache.struts.action.Action.saveToken(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Unable to apply any optimisations to advised method: protected java.lang.String org.apache.struts.action.Action.generateToken(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Unable to apply any optimisations to advised method: protected org.apache.struts.action.ActionMessages org.apache.struts.action.Action.getMessages(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Unable to apply any optimisations to advised method: protected javax.sql.DataSource org.apache.struts.action.Action.getDataSource(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Unable to apply any optimisations to advised method: protected javax.sql.DataSource org.apache.struts.action.Action.getDataSource(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.lang.String)
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Found finalize() method - using NO_OVERRIDE
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Found 'equals' method: public boolean java.lang.Object.equals(java.lang.Object)
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Unable to apply any optimisations to advised method: public java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Found 'hashCode' method: public native int java.lang.Object.hashCode()
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Unable to apply any optimisations to advised method: protected native java.lang.Object java.lang.Object.clone() throws java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Method is declared on Advised interface: public abstract int org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised.indexOf(org.springframework.aop.Advisor)
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Method is declared on Advised interface: public abstract int org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised.indexOf(org.aopalliance.aop.Advice)
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Method is declared on Advised interface: public abstract boolean org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised.isFrozen()
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Method is declared on Advised interface: public abstract org.springframework.aop.Advisor[] org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised.getAdvisors()
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Method is declared on Advised interface: public abstract boolean org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised.removeAdvice(org.aopalliance.aop.Advice)
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Method is declared on Advised interface: public abstract void org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised.addAdvice(org.aopalliance.aop.Advice) throws org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Method is declared on Advised interface: public abstract void org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised.addAdvice(int,org.aopalliance.aop.Advice) throws org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Method is declared on Advised interface: public abstract boolean org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised.isPreFiltered()
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Method is declared on Advised interface: public abstract java.lang.Class[] org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised.getProxiedInterfaces()
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Method is declared on Advised interface: public abstract boolean org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised.isInterfaceProxied(java.lang.Class)
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Method is declared on Advised interface: public abstract void org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised.removeAdvisor(int) throws org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Method is declared on Advised interface: public abstract boolean org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised.removeAdvisor(org.springframework.aop.Advisor)
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Method is declared on Advised interface: public abstract boolean org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised.replaceAdvisor(org.springframework.aop.Advisor,org.springframework.aop.Advisor) throws org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Method is declared on Advised interface: public abstract java.lang.String org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised.toProxyConfigString()
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Method is declared on Advised interface: public abstract org.springframework.aop.TargetSource org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised.getTargetSource()
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Method is declared on Advised interface: public abstract void org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised.setTargetSource(org.springframework.aop.TargetSource)
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Method is declared on Advised interface: public abstract void org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised.setPreFiltered(boolean)
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Method is declared on Advised interface: public abstract boolean org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised.isProxyTargetClass()
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Method is declared on Advised interface: public abstract void org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised.setExposeProxy(boolean)
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Method is declared on Advised interface: public abstract boolean org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised.isExposeProxy()
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Method is declared on Advised interface: public abstract void org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised.addAdvisor(org.springframework.aop.Advisor) throws org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Method is declared on Advised interface: public abstract void org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised.addAdvisor(int,org.springframework.aop.Advisor) throws org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy  - Method is declared on Advised interface: public abstract java.lang.Class org.springframework.aop.TargetClassAware.getTargetClass()
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Finished creating instance of bean 'transactionAction'
```

I also read quite a bit of info about abstract method calls and AOP but nothing seems to work. Please help me out.

Comment: ***Struts2 + Spring3*** would me A LOT better than ***Struts1 + Struts2 + Spring3*** (I suppose you can't change it, at least for this project, but please change the stack in the next one..:); 
+1 for the effort showed in the answer, and good luck :/

Comment: From what I have understood after looking at this for some time is that by connecting Spring and Struts in the above manner, Spring is not managing the Struts 1 Action itself because no Action beans have been created. It only allows for us to be able to autowire the service layer beans into Struts 1. To delete Struts action management to Spring we need to use the DelegatingActionProxy. Here is a good example I found - http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-sr2/index.html