# Struts 1.3 + Saml Okta SSO Integration

Tags: saml-2.0, spring-saml, okta, struts-1, okta-api

We want our (struts 1.3) application to integrate with SAML through Okta SSO. I searched in Google but not seen any example. Please Advise me on "(struts 1.3) application to integrate with SAML through Okta SSO" and give some sample codes.

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

Okta has a relevant guide for integrating Spring Security SAML here: http://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/spring_security_saml.html

Spring also has some documentation on the topic: http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-saml/1.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/chapter-idp-guide.html#d5e1816

Comment: Before posting my question in stackoverflow. I seen all the relevant Guide in both Spring site and Okta Site. But not got any clear idea of Struts 1.3 Integration with Okta through SAML.

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this is to do an integration your Struts 1.3 app with Spring Security first.  I have not done this integration myself - but there seems to be a few threads on this subject - if you search for "struts spring security"

[How to integrate an old Struts application with Spring 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835910/how-to-integrate-an-old-struts-application-with-spring-3-x)

https://spring3mvc.wordpress.com/2012/06/25/spring-security-with-struts-1-3/

http://classfoundexception.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-secure-struts-13-application.html

Afterwards, follow the guidance here - http://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/spring_security_saml.html - to SAML-enable your app.  You will then configure an app instance in Okta to make Okta as the IDP of your application.  I don't have anything more detailed than this as I haven't tried this myself - but hopefully, this will lead you down the right path.